# Android studio- application in emulator stopped

Tags: android, genymotion

This is the coding to create a shopping list that can de edited or delete when user clicked on the items.

I followed the examples given in web but for some reason, the application just stopped before it can execute anything. I have checked couple of times but cant seems to find any solution. Am I missing something? Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ArrayList<String> shoppingList=null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= null;
ListView lv=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());

    Collections.sort(shoppingList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,shoppingList);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if (selectedItem.trim().equals(shoppingList.get(position).trim())) {
                removeElement(selectedItem, position);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Removing Element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
//inflate menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id=item.getItemId();

    if(id==R.id.action_add){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Item");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                shoppingList.add(preferredCase(input.getText().toString()));
                Collections.sort(shoppingList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static String preferredCase(String original)
{
    if (original.isEmpty())
        return original;

    return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

public static void storeArrayVal( ArrayList<String> inArrayList, Context context)
{
    Set<String> WhatToWrite = new HashSet<String>(inArrayList);
    SharedPreferences WordSearchPutPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("dbArrayValues", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = WordSearchPutPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putStringSet("myArray", WhatToWrite);
    prefEditor.commit();
}

public static ArrayList getArrayVal( Context dan)
{
    SharedPreferences WordSearchGetPrefs = dan.getSharedPreferences("dbArrayValues",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
    tempSet = WordSearchGetPrefs.getStringSet("myArray", tempSet);
    return new ArrayList<String>(tempSet);
}

public void removeElement(String selectedItem, final int position){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Remove " + selectedItem + "?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            shoppingList.remove(position);
            Collections.sort(shoppingList);
            storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
    }
}
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shoppinglist">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

error message

```
12-23 23:36:43.038 1259-1259/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-23 23:36:43.594 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-23 23:36:43.626 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-23 23:36:43.626 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17907: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-23 23:36:43.630 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-23 23:36:43.646 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-23 23:36:43.650 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17911: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-23 23:36:43.654 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-23 23:36:43.786 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-23 23:36:43.790 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-23 23:36:43.794 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-23 23:36:43.794 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-23 23:36:43.798 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 454: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-23 23:36:43.798 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-23 23:36:43.826 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
12-23 23:36:43.830 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18422: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
12-23 23:36:43.830 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
12-23 23:36:43.834 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
12-23 23:36:43.834 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18422: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
12-23 23:36:43.838 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ba9648)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shyan.shoppinglist/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shyan.shoppinglist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
12-23 23:36:43.966 1259-1259/com.example.shyan.shoppinglist E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: when you say stopped, does it give you any error or exception..if it does then attach that too.

Comment: You are passing `shoppingList` as `null` to `storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());`, thats why its crashing.

Comment: may i ask what should i add?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this line,

```
 storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
```

You should initialise your array before you pass.

```
ArrayList<String> shoppingList=null;
```

should be 
    ArrayList shoppingList=new ArrayList();

OR 
Replace your line,

```
storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
```

with,

```
shoppingList=new ArrayList(); 
storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: the application still stop. i edited my post with the logcat

Comment: post your logcat. So we can help you.

Comment: Are u using any lib files? And which IDE? Android studio or eclipse?

Comment: I'm using android studio. android sdk. genymotion. wat does lib files mean?

Comment: If you have used any .jar file in your app of lib folder and it's not added to your build path then it may cause this kind of error. What is `Landroid/view/SearchEvent` ? in you code